# Elasticsearch hanging at startup

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to run Elasticsearch with the default settings, without any data. I just unpack the tarball and run ./bin/elasticsearch. The problem is that it just hangs forever. Nothing in the logs, no output on stdout. This is a machine that has potentially security restrictions and ressource access control policies in place.

```
$ ./bin/elasticsearch -V
Version: 5.2.2, Build: f9d9b74/2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z, JVM: 1.8.0_111
```

Linux version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux [...] 2.6.18-406.el5 #1 SMP Fri May 1 10:37:57 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
```

Java:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Tail of strace output:

```
[...]
mmap(0x3f61a00000, 2629848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3f61a00000
mprotect(0x3f61a82000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3f61c81000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x81000) = 0x3f61c81000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x3f61c81000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
access("/path/to/elasticsearch-5.2.2/lib/*", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/path/to/elasticsearch-5.2.2/lib/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 35 entries */, 32768)    = 1592
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x2b25d806b000
mprotect(0x2b25d806b000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x2b25d816b250, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x2b25d816b9d0, tls=0x2b25d816b940, child_tidptr=0x2b25d816b9d0) = 9136
futex(0x2b25d816b9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 9136, NULL
```

Trace of a child thread repeatedly prints:

```
futex(0x148e954, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {0, 756577000}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x148e928, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698412, 584730159}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698412, 584758159}) = 0
futex(0x148e954, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {4, 999972000}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x148e928, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698417, 586260159}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698417, 586288159}) = 0
futex(0x148e954, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {4, 999972000}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x148e928, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698422, 586801159}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698422, 586831159}) = 0
futex(0x148e954, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, {4, 999970000}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x148e928, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698427, 588349159}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {18698427, 588380159}) = 0
```

It always block on that same call. I have a very similar machine where Elasticsearch starts just fine. I can't figure out what difference make it start on one machine and hang on the other.

Comment: I guess you are watching the parent thread. Run something like "ps -efL | grep java" to get the spawned threads and then execute strace with that pids to see whats really going on within the child threads.

Comment: Thanks, edited to add info about child thread.

Comment: Could you share your elasticsearch config? (e.g. elasticsearch.yml, and so on if you have other config files)

Comment: @asettouf I use the default config. I just unpack the tarball and run ./bin/elasticsearch. Editing to add this information to my question.

Comment: What you could try as well is start elasticsearch in debug mode with `./elasticsearch -Des.logger.level=DEBUG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this issue was caused by a failing NFS mount point. Apparently, Elasticsearch goes through NFS mount points and hangs if one of them is hanged.